# Is there some order in this confusing mess about time, energy, position, and momentum?

Tags: energy, momentum, time, space

Time can be considered the zeroth component of the position four-vector. To fit the units you have to multiply it by c, the lightspeed, and sometimes its multiplied by i, the imaginary.

Likewise, energy can be considered the zeroth component of the momentum four-vector. To match the momentum unit it's divided by c.

The four momentum is the mass times the time derivative of the four-position. which gives $E=mc^2$.

The relation between the two vectors can be seen in the uncertainty relations. One for energy and time, the time components, and one for the spatial parts, position and momentum.

Then there is the Schrödinger equation. The energy corresponds to the partial time derivative, $i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$. On the other side of the equation we find the Hamiltonian, $H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2+V$, so we can see a correspondence between the partial derivative in position, and that in time.

There is a relation between energy, time, position, and momentum. Momentum needs two positions, and time is needed between two positions to determine momentum. Two different zeroth components ($ct$) are needed to obtain the time derivative of that zeroth component, so the time derivative of the time! For which proper time ($\tau$) or coordinate time ($t$) can be used.

It's all a bit confusing, and if the question seems to be posed confusingly, that's because it **is** confusing (to me,).
Time is not a variable (how on Earth you wanna vary it? Tinkering with the buttons on the back side of the alarm clock?). Neither is it an operator, but you can let it act (the partial derivative, that is) on the wave function, which is equivalent to operate on the wavefunction with a Hamiltonian. The Hamiltonian, on its turn, can be used as the generator for time translations, like the 3-momentum can be used for space translations (again, the position and momentum four-vectors appear in sight here).
Time is a parameter.

Is there some kind of neat ordering in this confusing mess?

Comment: Sure, it is called Lorentz transformations and four vectors. http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html

Comment: Trying to fit the Schroedinger equation into a relativistic picture would naturally be confusing because it's not relativistic.